# Why do my fans spin loudly after a Windows OS restart?

Tags: windows, motherboard, windows-11, fan

Correct behavior: When I start my PC, the PC fans are almost immediately set to very quiet by the Gigabyte BIOS ("Smart Fan 6" feature). And once Windows starts, they're correctly controlled to be very quiet by the software [Fan Control](https://github.com/Rem0o/FanControl.Releases). When I wake the PC from sleep, the fans also stay quiet.

Problem: When I restart the PC from within Windows (e.g. via power icon -> Restart, or Update and Restart), then upon restart all fans run at max. speed. This problem persists until I login to Windows, because then the Fan Control software takes over.

My own troubleshooting: I've already contacted Gigabyte eSupport about this matter, but they only suggested that Windows, rather their own hardware, was at fault.

---

System specs

- OS: Windows 11 Pro N (64-bit)
- Case: Torrent Compact by Fractal Design
- Motherboard: [Gigabyte B660M DS3H DDR4 (1.0)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B660M-DS3H-DDR4-rev-10), BIOS ver. F21
- Fan connections: The two big Torrent fans are connected to a fan hub, which is connected to one of the system fan headers; the CPU fan is in the CPU fan header, and a Noctua case fan is connected to another system fan header. All fan connectors are 4-pin PWM.

---

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem could be, or at least which hardware components or which software could be responsible, or how I can find out?

Comment: When you "restart" you are properly resetting the motherboard controller, whereas modern "shutdown" is simply hibernating the operating system core and putting the motherboard into deep sleep (essentially off but chips may not be reset). It seems that coming out of that hibernation the fan controller is using the settings last applied by the software while a reboot will properly clear those settings. It sounds like your BIOS is therefore not applying its own settings, or those settings are for "high speed" rather than automatic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explanation gave me sth to test.

1) I temporarily disabled Fast Startup and Hibernation via Wintoys, and confirmed they were disabled via cmd -> "powercfg /availablesleepstates". 2) Then I shut down the PC, rebooted it, observed the fan noise until the OS was loaded, and finally I repeated this step once.

3) Result: The behavior after shutdown was unaffected: On boot, the fans slow down to my settings roughly once I see the Gigabyte BIOS splash screen.

Comment: Did you also disable fast boot in the BIOS?

Comment: So hibernation does not affect my fan problem. However, your suggestion re: the BIOS potentially not appling its own fan control settings, is consistent with this quote from [here](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/restarting-shutting-down-computer.htm): "Restarting... involves the operating system shutting itself down to the point where Windows will reload, but typically does not go the extra step of having to go through the motherboard boot loading process." -> Maybe this motherboard boot loading step is skipped on Windows restart, and thus the BIOS fan control step is somehow not applied.

Comment: > Did you also disable fast boot in the BIOS? -> No, I wasn't aware that there was one more thing I could disable. I can try that, too.

Comment: I checked my BIOS and Fast Boot was already disabled (Gigabyte calls this setting "Disable Link"). So I tried enabling it instead ("Ultra Fast" setting) and rebooted and restarted the PC a whole bunch, with and without hibernation enabled. Result: It seemed like there was one single time where the fans behaved correctly on restart, but I couldn't reproduce this behavior despite changing a bunch of stuff. The rest of the time, the fans were unaffected. || Separately, I discovered that on restart, the fans continued spinning at max speed even when I entered BIOS and opened the Fan Control panel.